# Wrong href of dynamically created "a" (anchor) element on archive.org site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I use this code to create "a" element to add it to the page. (On 3rd party site, it's a userscript)

```js
let anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.href = new URL("https://duckduckgo.com");
console.log(anchor);

//anchor.target = "_blank";
//anchor.rel = "nofollow noopener noreferrer";
//anchor.click();
```

*Run this code in the console to check it.*

This code works OK on all sites, except some pages on `web.archive.org`

For example:

on https://web.archive.org/web/19961220154510/https://www.yahoo.com/

I get
`<a href="https://web.archive.org/web/19961220154510if_/https://duckduckgo.com/"></a>`,

but should `<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/"></a>`.

`.click()` (on it) opens this wrong URL.

How to fix it?

It happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

---

UPD: `window.open("https://duckduckgo.com")` works wrong too.

It opens `https://web.archive.org/web/20080820060021/http://duckduckgo.com/` instead `https://duckduckgo.com/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because Javascript on that site is overwriting `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.href`:

[image]

Overwriting native prototypes is bad practice and results in confusing errors like these.

For a userscript, you can fix it by saving a reference to the `href` property descriptor at the beginning of pageload, then reassign it to `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.href` after the bad built-in code has tried to reassign it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             0 New Userscript
// @include          https://web.archive.org/web/19961220154510/https://www.yahoo.com/
// @run-at           document-start
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

const originalHrefDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, 'href');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, 'href', originalHrefDescriptor);
  // Now, assigning to .hrefs results in normal behavior again
});
```

Make sure to use `// @run-at           document-start` to ensure your userscript runs before any code on the page runs - that way, you can save a reference to the descriptor before it gets overwritten.

For this particular situation with wombat, you can also give the `a` a `_no_rewrite` property instead of saving the descriptor:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a._no_rewrite = true;
a.href = 'https://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the problem was about that the site URL contains another URL. Wow, I have never heard about `_no_rewrite`, but it works.

Comment: Upd: `_no_rewrite` it is not a standard attribute, but it is a part of wombat.js API. (just a note)

Comment: Yeah, the `_no_rewrite` thing is *only* applicable for working around this particular wombat's sillyness